# Does Android automatically delete obb expansion files after install?

Tags: android, android-install-apk, apk-expansion-files

I have an obb file which is a zip file, which I unpack after downloading it in the obb folder. Then I copy the unpacked obb files to Internal Storage.

I just released an app to Internal testing. I installed the app, but I was hoping that the obb files would be automatically deleted, but it seems they are still hanging in there, and when I check the Storage size in Settings, the size of the apk file includes the data in the obb folder. I don't want this, because my app is taking less storage then it's actually showing in Settings / Storage.

Is there an Android process that automatic removes the obb files later on, or do I need to delete them myself when I don't need them anymore, right after copying them to internal storage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. The only time the OBB file gets deleted is when the user uninstalls the app. Or when the app deletes the file itself.

On a side note, which I happened to find out only later, if you delete or rename your OBB file, it gets re-downloaded every time you release an app update. So you are better off using the OBB file as is and leave it there as originally installed, and using a second OBB file for updates (your listed app size will include the OBB file though), or another option is using a file hosting service such as Dropbox if you don't want the OBB file just sitting there.

Comment: Sorry to go somewhat off-topic, but do you know an answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520756/do-android-apps-still-need-to-contain-an-expansion-files-downloader)? Even if it's quite old

Comment: Yes, I answered the question. Hope it helps.